# What does "respectively" mean in the Tenth Amendment?

Tags: united-states, constitution, law

The Tenth Amendment to the United States Constitution states "The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States respectively, or to the people."  My question is, what does "respectively" mean here?

Is it comparing the states and the people, with the "respectively" put in an odd place due to archaic language, where we might say in modern language "to the States or the people respectively", akin to "George Washington and John Adams were the first and second Presidents respectively."?  If that's the construction being used, what would it mean?  Are the "powers not delegated" reserved to the States, with the powers not prohibited reserved to the people?

Or does "respectively" mean individually or separately, something like "reserved to each of the individual States, or to the people"?  If that's the meaning, then what is the force of the "or"?  Are there some circumstances in which the powers are reserved to the States, and others in which they are reserved to the people?  If so, what are these circumstances?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Belongs on English Language SE

Answer (score 3):

It reads as "the powers reserved to the respective states," meaning "relating separately to each of the states." Without this word, the sentence would sound weird as if the states had to exercise their *individual* powers all together.
The Ninth Amendment is about the rights retained by the people. Although it does not specify any particular rights, it states that the people *do* have them. The most common interpretation of such rights is that *the “rights retained by the people” refer to the inalienable and natural rights as articulated in 18th century America, chief among them the right to self-government.* (cited from [here](http://www.heritage.org/constitution/#!/amendments/9/essays/162/rights-retained-by-the-people))

The Ninth and the Tenth Amendments are, thus, complementary, confirming the separate powers of the respective states and preserving the rights of the people in all matters not delegated to the US government. [Here](http://www.law.cornell.edu/anncon/html/amdt10_user.html) is a detailed discussion on the purpose and effect of the Tenth Amendment.

Comment: If you're right that "respectively" means "separately", then what does the "or the people" part in the tenth amendment?  (I'm not talking about the ninth amendment here.). What is the force of that "or"?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - In a way yes but seperately would be the wrong word.  Basically the language says in absence of reserving the right to the USG the states can chose to reserve the right for themselves, in absense of that the right is reserved to the people.  Good luck trying to get a court to rule that way these days though

Comment: Where are you getting the notion that it's up to the States whether the power gets to be reserved to the States or the people?  I don't see how the language says that at all.

Comment: Keshav Srinivasan, as @Chad has already answered, powers not granted to the US government are reserved to the states, and powers not exercised by the states are reserved to the people. Try to imagine the X Amendment _without_ the phrase "or to the people." Then the IX Amendment would not have had any sense, because there would have been no rights retained by the people, as all powers were divided only between the US and the states.

Comment: @I.M. Where are you getting the idea that the only powers reserved to the people are the ones that the States don't choose to exercise?  The amendment doesn't say that.

Comment: Keshav Srinivasan, could you name any powers, which belong to the states or to the US, that the people would be able to exercise individually? Defense, business regulations, tax collection, health care system, education system, ecology, road construction, anything?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - Actually it is not the ONLY powers reserved to the people.  Those rights expressly protected by the the constitution are also the rights of the people that can not be infringed on.  This amendment simply says anything not protected from or explicitly granted to the government, is intended to be considered a right of the people.

Comment: @I.M.  I'm just basing it off of what you said: "powers not exercised by the states are reserved to the people".  What did you mean by that, other than the notion that there are certain powers that the states can exercise, but if they don't exercise them then the people can?  If that is the notion you were articulating, where do you see that in the language of the tenth amendment?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In my previous comment, I was trying to clarify whether you do understand the functions of government. Yet, it seems that you don't. There are certain powers that the states **must** exercise because the people cannot. It is not in the text of the Tenth Amendment, it is the meaning of governance, it is what the states' powers are meant for. Please consult a textbook on public policy and governance before continuing any discussion about the meaning of the US constitution.

Comment: @I.M.  I understand the functions of government just fine.  I was just trying to decipher the meaning of your statement that "powers not exercised by the states are reserved to the people", which suggested that you thought that there are powers that either the states or the people could exercise, and the ones that the states do not exercise are reserved to the people.  If that's not what you were trying to say, what did you mean?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan OK, now I see where this misunderstanding comes from. There is no "either... or..." meaning in that sentence. The government must use certain powers for the well-being of the whole community because the people could not exercise those powers. Nonetheless, the people still have a lot of rights and powers--everything that is not the powers of the states or of the US government. For example, there is federal commerce law, there are many states' trade laws and by-laws, but the businessmen decide upon trade contracts among themselves and perform those contracts themselves, too.

Comment: One interpretation I've seen is that without “or to the people” the Tenth would be a sweeping grant of all conceivable residual powers, overriding (through the Supremacy Clause) any restrictions in the respective States' constitutions.  The phrase recognizes that the ultimate sovereign is the People, who hold (in potential) all political power, and delegate some of it to their various governments.